# Run a query (create procedure) in .net (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like below,how can i execute it from code (in C#) ?
I can run this query in sql server.

```
create procedure addSystemError
    @date Datetime,
    @type nvarchar(50),
    @des nvarchar(max)
as
    insert into SystemError values(@date,@type,@des)
GO


create procedure loadSystemErrorCount
    @startDate datetime,
    @endDate datetime,
    @type nvarchar(50)
as
    if(@type='All')
        select COUNT(*) from SystemError where date>=@startDate and date<@endDate
    else
        select COUNT(*) from SystemError where date>=@startDate and date<@endDate and type=@type
Go
```

Comment: I want to run a query,maybe in this query exist more than a store procedure

Comment: You have to separate it into two SQL commands - one for each `create procedure` call - and then execute those one after the other.

Comment: If I want to create second procedure loadSystemErrorCount, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("addSystemError", conn) { 
                       CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) {
 conn.Open();

 /* Add the parameters in command
  .    
  . 
  .
 */

 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: run a query that contains store procedure,select ....,update , ...

Answer (score -1):

this should work:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

[Microsoft how to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Comment: comment would be sufficient if the answer is mostly a link..

Comment: thanks i will remember this and change my answer

Comment: -1 for no `using` blocks.

Comment: this is only a simple sample, do i have to add using blocks also in this? it's a sample from microsoft ;)